# how to escape string before use in query

Tags: php, mysql

how to escape this string

```
$sql = 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test\\import-excel\\book1.csv\\" INTO TABLE exam FIELDS TERMINATED BY  "," ';
```

because path to file will be a variable i don't know how to escape the path before use it in query , i used phpmyadmin ( create php code ) and it's gave me escaped string so i can use that , i hope someone can tell me about what function phpmyadmin use to generate this string from orginal string

```
$sql = "\'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE \"C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs\\\\test\\\\import-excel\\\\book1.csv\\\\\" INTO TABLE exam FIELDS TERMINATED BY \",\" \';";
```

tanks

Comment: What string? The one that starts with `$sql`? The one that starts with `LOAD DATA`? Or the one that starts with `C:\\xampp`?

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php

Comment: i have use it already but it's gave me this error : LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE \"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test\\import-excel\\book1.csv\\\" INTO TABLE exam FIELDS TERMINATED BY \",\" Errormessage: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test\\import-excel\\book1.csv\\\" INTO TABLE exam FIELDS TE' at line 1